# jQuery fancybox loads iframe in less HTML page but not on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm having difficulty finding which jQuery plugin or something else in Wordpress that is not allowing to load iframe with fancybox.

Easy Fancybox with stripped html works and below is the working version

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' id='easy-fancybox.css-css'  href='http://www.wp-responsive-themes.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/easy-fancybox.css.php?ver=1.3.4' type='text/css' media='screen' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.wp-responsive-themes.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=1.3.4'></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://wp-responsive-themes.com/"  data-fancybox-type="iframe"  title="preview" class="preview fancybox-iframe">Preview</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.preview").fancybox({
           'Width'    :       960 ,
           'Height'   :       640,
           'hideOnContentClick': false, 
           'type':'iframe'
      }); 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but fancybox can't load iframe on the page (Wordpress).

The iframe was supposed to open when "iPhone 5 Vertical Orientation Preview" is clicked
at the following page

http://www.wp-responsive-themes.com/2012/myapp-adaptive-wp-theme-for-app-developers-429/

Need Help

Kind Regards

Comment: The image loads with fancybox but not iframe in the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is setup in such a way that jQuery is to be used without conflicts.  This means $ is not readily available.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("a.iphone4_vertical").fancybox({
           'Width'    :       960 ,
           'Height'   :       640,
           'hideOnContentClick': false, 
           'type':'iframe'
      }); 
});
```

Adding the `$` as a function parameter should solve your issue.

Comment: @AnupRaj : also make sure that `width` and `height` have no caps (js parameters are case sensitive)